# Retrieving a directory location by any means

Tags: php, html, xhtml, directory

I need to retrieve the location of a file or directory.  It would basically be like:

```
/< input type="file"/>
```

but I would only need to return me the location of the file or directory.

I don't have an issue with the file use case currently, but I cannot find a solution for the directory use case.  I've looked around online and seen people saying it cannot be done with just html and I would need to use PHP or Flash.  Flash isn't exactly an option, so does anyone have any tips on doing this with PHP or just any suggestions in general?

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: The information you require is not submitted when the browser makes its request. It's not retrievable using PHP. I can see why Flash is an option, because it's client side run, so you can control what information is sent.

Comment: Which directory are you talking about? The directory on the client computer where the file is located before it is uploaded to the server?

Comment: First this seems hacky. On the question - different browsers shows different kind of info, and not everyone will show you from what directory the file is uploaded.

Comment: I'm looking for the directory on the client computer where the file is located.  Believe it or not, I am not actually concerned with uploading the file at all, just selecting directories and file locations.

Answer (score 0):

This is too much of a security risk for a browser to allow by default. You will need to be able to run code on the client machine to retrieve the directory, so client-side solutions like Flash or ActiveX are your only options.